# Leaderboards not working after App was released on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-games

I implemented Leaderboards on my app and during testing, the Leaderboards were working during that time. Upon release, the APK downloaded from the Play Store does not show any Leaderboards at all, it is stuck in the loading screen.

The steps I did to try to resolve this issue

1. Got my release SHA1 key using keytool -exportcert -keystore C:\Users\"NAME"\.android\debug.keystore -list -v
2. Deleted all the existing OAuth 2.0 client IDs in Google APIs and created a new Linked App using this new SHA1 fingerprint (Renamed my existing Linked Apps so it would be positioned in the bottom). Consequently a new OAuth Client ID was created in Google APIs. The OAuth2 Client ID in Game Services and Google APIs is exactly the same.
3. The Leaderboards in the Release app is still not working.

Please help!

Comment: After installing my app from Android Studio to my physical phone once again, the Leaderboards are working there. I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Did you try and test the signed apk by placing it on your phone and installing it? Also, did you use proGaurd?

Comment: After I read your comment, I transferred my signed APK to my phone and used that to install the app. Interestingly, the Leaderboards does not work that way. I was unfamiliar with proGuard and a quick google shows that proGuard assists in "Shrinking Your Code", should I try to follow the guide here? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: I've experienced strange behaviou with ProGaurd in the past, I would try disabling it and see if the problem is resolved. Let me know, would like to know...